# Tool for html formatting

Tags: html, user-interface

I am new with html and at times, I miss or misplace my html tags

example: `<tr> <td> </tr> </td>` or similar mistakes.

Please suggest me a way/tools to validate the format of my html files.

It would be great if the tool can solve my two issues:

1. Format of html document
2. Suggest any missing tags for example: If i have missed `<table>` and just added `<tr>` and `<td>`, the tool should suggest me to include

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Which editor you'd be used.?

Comment: @Ajay I have edited my post with more details, I mostly use notepad++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which editor you use, but you can maybe install a linter for you editor, the most popular editors does support extensions so you can install a linter, and some editors have built-in code correction.

**What is a linter?**

> A linter is a small program that checks code for stylistic or
>   programming errors. Linters are available for most syntaxes, from
>   Python to HTML.

source: [sublimelinter](http://www.sublimelinter.com/en/latest/about.html#what-is-a-linter)

**Atom editor - free and open source**

For example the Atom editor have some linter packages (extensions) out there for different languages.

Atom HTML linter packages: [HTML linter packages for Atom](https://atom.io/packages/search?q=html%20linter)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using programs such as Sublime text, that gives you colour schemes for certain tags, or Adobes Brackets; it auto guesses what tags youre about to use basically so you cant go wrong!